# android - facebook settings for hackbook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am newbie to facebook android sdk. I run the Hackbook app in the samples and it's working fine. Now, I try to retrieve the posts of the fb account using Hackbook App ID(i.e., from samples). this time also it's working fine. But Now i created the app in fb developer console and i used that App Id in the hackbook instead of old ID. This time i am not getting the likes and comments of the Post. For this I did in fb developer console.

1. I create the app in facebook developer.
2. I get the keyhash from the cmd and set this in the native android app.
3. I set the all the permission in the hackbook like  "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins","photo_upload" in the permissions tab.
4. For retrieving the likes and comments of the post, Which permission are required in the FB and what we do for working this?
5. In the following image, By default sandbox  is enabled,in this case fb login is not working. After that i make it as disabled then only fb login is working in th Hackbook app. Why?

[image]